# Cannot install Pecl (Imagick) extension on Centos server - autoconf missing

Tags: php, centos, pecl

I'm trying to install the pecl extension Imagick on a centos server, but I'm getting an error about autoconf.
Autoconf is installed, as is make and gcc. but it's complaining about the path:

```
[root@server ~]# pecl install imagick
downloading imagick-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.0.1.tgz (93,920 bytes)
.....................done: 93,920 bytes
13 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
/usr/bin/phpize: /var/tmp/imagick/build/shtool: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission     denied
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

    ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a problem with the /bin/sh command which on centos is a link to /bin/bash. Check that the command is executable.

ls -l /bin/sh
ls -l /bin/bash

If the link does not exist create it.

Comment: cheers. you are correct, of course. I found this: http://blog.ntrippy.net/2008/06/installing-peclpear-php-modules-on-rhel.html